# How to call a Javascript function defined in a QML file from another QML file?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

```
     ...<other code>
     MouseArea
      {
        anchors.fill: parent

        onClicked:
        {
          console.log ("You clicked on tab!");


          TabContainers.tabClicked (index);
        }
      }
     ...<other code>
```

This code in the file `X.qml`. Another file named `TabContainers.qml` contains a function named `tabClicked`.

I wish to call that function in file `X.qml`, so I tried:
`TabContainers.tabClicked (index);`

This gave me the error:
`ReferenceError: TabContainers is not defined`

**How to call a function defined in a QML file in another QML file?**

**UPDATE:**

---

This is what I tried:

**TestB.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle 
{
  id: myItem
  width: 100; height: 100

  function f ()
  {
    console.log ("sadsad");
  }
}
```

**TestA.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item 
{
  width: 100; height: 100

  Loader 
  {
    id: myLoader
    source: "TestB.qml"
  }

  Connections 
  {
    target: myLoader.f()
  }
}
```

and the error I get is:
`TestA.qml:15: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'f'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/56598-How-to-call-a-Javascript-function-defined-in-a-QML-file-from-another-QML-file?p=253017#post253017):

Instead of this:

`myLoader.item.f()`

I was rather calling `f()` like this: `myLoader.f()`

Answer (score 2):

You need to load a `TabContainers` instance in your current QML and call the function `tabClicked()` on it for it to work.

If your `TabContainers` instance is loaded in another QML file of your application you could also define a `signal` in one of their common ancestor and emit the signal in `X.qml` and catch it in `TabContainers.qml` using the [Connections](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qml-qtquick2-connections.html) component.

If your `TabContainers` instance is loaded in a parent of where `X.qml` is loaded you could also reference the id of your `TabContainers` instance to call the function.

Example of the second solution

**Parent.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle 
{
  id: rootItem
  width: 300; height: 300

  signal handleTabClicked(int value);

  A {
    id: myElemA
    anchors.left: parent.left
  }

  B {
    id: myElemB
    anchors.right: parent.right
  }
}
```

**A.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle 
{
  id: myItem
  width: 80; height: 80
  color: "yellow"

  Connections {
    target: rootItem
    onHandleTabClicked: {
      f();
    }
  }

  function f ()
  {
    console.log ("sadsad");
  }
}
```

**B.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle 
{
  id: myItem
  width: 150; height: 150
  color: "red"
  MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: {
      rootItem.handleTabClicked(4);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I added an example in my question. But it is really hard to understand what you want to do and it might be easier to explain with a real example

Comment: How do you get the argument in onHandleTabClicked: ?